# jsonschema and validate-json don't validate "required"

Tags: json

Schema is:

```
{
    "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",

    "header": {
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
            "token":         { "type": "string" },
            "id":            { "type": "number" },
            "command":       { "type": "string" }
        },
        "required": ["token", "id", "command"]
    }
}
```

But things like that are ok for the validators:

```
{
    "badtoken": "abc123",
    "badcommand": "123"
}
```

Command lines:

```
$ jsonschema -i file.json schema.json

$ validate-json file.json schema.json
```

Why it's not working?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I wanted to make a list of definitions and then use them:

```
{
    "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",

    "definitions": {
        "header": {
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
                "token":         { "type": "string" },
                "id":            { "type": "number" },
                "command":       { "type": "string" }
            },
            "required": ["token", "id", "command"]
        }
    },

    "$ref": "#/definitions/header"
}
```

Validation works as expected.